# Finding neighbor nodes in graph connection Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, nodes

I am working on a path finding problem. I have a 2D grid of evenly spaced nodes. I need an algorithm to find all 8 neighbors (if they exist) for each node so I can find all neighbor connections.

The only way I know how to do it would be something like this:

```
for each node
 for every other node
     check position to find if it is neighboring if so add it to the nodes connection list
```

My concern is that this would be pretty inefficient `O(n^2)` and I imagine there is a better way of solving it.

Any help would be great!

Comment: It is just an array of the nodes each having an x and y. If a good method requires a different way of storing the nodes that would be fine too.

Comment: @templatetypedef This post really needed a 2D tag?

Comment: My apologies - I was under the impression that 2D was the tag for general two-dimensional objects, not two-dimensional graphics.  I've removed the tag accordingly.  Sorry about that!

Comment: @templatetypedef No problem, I just thought it was funny you took effort to edit that, after looking at that though I did see you added data structures which is useful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One simple option would be to store the nodes themselves in a two-dimensional array indexed by the x and y coordinates of the nodes.  That way, you'd have O(1) random access to the node stored at position (x, y) by just indexing into the array and looking at what's there.

Alternatively, if your nodes are sparse, you could consider storing the nodes in a hash table keyed by the (x, y) location.  This also gives O(1) random access to nodes at given positions, and with a simple double for-loop you could list off all eight neighbors.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The x and y are stored as floats, is it possible that the floats from my loop and node position could hash differently sometimes? (if so ill just cast to an int to be safe)

Comment: If you're storing them as floats, you may need to do this completely differently.  Why are they stored as floats?  And what counts as a "neighbor?"

Comment: I can avoid floats if it simplifies the solution

Comment: @JustinMeiners- If everything has integer positions, I'd strongly suggest using integers.  If you're working with more general nodes that can be placed at real-valued locations, I can suggest a more powerful data structure that's capable of handling that.